# Do I need to implement my doorman if I want to fully control the node access to the network

Tags: corda

Hope someone can help me on this.

My understanding from Corda docs is that Corda network is a semi-private. Seems to me that everyone sends a CSR with required information (legalname & emailaddress as in Corda example) to the doorman (there is limited detail about the doorman, but I know that Corda will provide one), will then get certificates and access to the network.

My Questions:

- If I want to fully control who (the node) can access to the network,
  do I need to build my own doorman service?
- Will the doorman also act as an intermediate CA to sign the certificates?

Regards,
Kwan

Answer (score 2):

The Doorman in Corda network receives Certificate Signing Request and distribute signed certificate once the CSR has been approved. All the certificates issued by the doorman will have the same root certificate, thats what enables nodes to connect to each other to form a Corda network.

So, you don't really need a doorman if you want control on who have access to the network, you only need to make sure you are the one controlling the root CA/intermediate CA, you can create the certificate for each node manually using any key tools or by using Corda's [X509Utilities](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/crypto/X509Utilities.kt) (which uses Bouncy Castle). You can look at [ConfigUtilities](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/config/ConfigUtilities.kt)`.createKeystoreForCordaNode` for how to create a valid keystore for Corda node.

For the second question, in non-production network the doorman can act as the intermediate CA, but it should be done by Hardware Security Module (HSM) in production network.